# in C#, How to access base class variable value from child class

Tags: c#, inheritance

**Base Class**

```
class TestBase
{
    protected int a;
    protected int b;

    public TestBase(int i)
    {
        a = i;
    }

    protected TestBase()
    {

    }

    public void Update(int i)
    {
        a = i;

        TestChild child = new TestChild();
        child.Update("Hello World ");
    }
```

**Child Class**

```
class TestChild:TestBase
{
    private string msg;
    public void Update (string s)
    {
        msg = s+ a.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("msg=" + msg);

    }

}
```

**Calling**

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestBase t = new TestBase(1);
        t.Update(100);

    }
```

**Result**
Hello World 0

**Problem**
I was hoping to get Hello World 100. Obviously the child class did not access base class variable int a. how can I do that?

Comment: Why are you creating a `TestChild` instance inside `TestBase.Update`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should create `TestChild` int your main not in your Base class

Comment: Why the downvote? He is clearly stated his question: what he did so far, what the wrong result is and what he is expecting. If you don't like how he is coding then you have a good theme for your answer. Stop stealing points from people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you'd like to get the expected result, put a `static` modifier front of `a` and/or `b` variables, like this:

```
  static protected int a;
  static protected int b;
```

After this, if you push that button it will write out:

```
msg=Hello World 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The *child* object inside your TestBase doesn't know where is he placed. It doesn't know it is inside of a class.

When you create the *child* you also create a totally different TestBase object which is not the same as what contains the *child*. When you create that object *a* will be initialized to a default value which is 0 in this case.

If you would like to carry the value of a to an other object you should give it to it. For example through the constructor.

---

Call like this:

```
TestChild child = new TestChild(a);
```

Make a constructor like this:

```
public TestChild(int x) : base(x){}
```

---

Unfortunately your concept bleeding from everywhere so it will not work in this form. I recommend to study [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) more.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

There are many problems with this code. First, you should not be creating an instance of TestChild inside a TestBase class method. If you create an instance of TestBase inside btnTest_Click, then there is no way you'll be able to access any of TestChild's methods or data (except that you are creating an instance of TestChild inside TestBase which is bad practice).

The purpose of inheritance is usually to extend the data/methods for a base class, not to use an inherited class inside a base class. Also, with a set of inherited classes, you can achieve polymorphism which is another core principle of Object Oriented Programming. You should get a better understanding of these principles and then the code will start making more sense.

Answer (score 0):

The object you created in `TestBtn_Click` has nothing to do with the object you created in `TestBase.Update`. They are two different objects so each have their own `a` field with different values.

To produce the output you expect, you need to set `child.a` to `this.a` in `Update`:

```
public void Update(int i)
{
    a = i;

    TestChild child = new TestChild();
    child.a = this.a;
    child.Update("Hello World ");
}
```

The important thing to understand here is that inheritance does not affect objects. Inheritance only affects classes. The base class members will also be present in the subclass. That's it. **Even though `objA`'s type inherits from `objB`, they are unrelated unless they are the same object.**

Answer (score 0):

you should call your base class this way

```
class BaseClass
{
    int a;
    int b;
    protected BaseClass()
    { }

    protected BaseClass(int i)
    {
        a = i;
    }

    protected void Update(int i)
    {
        a = i;

        Console.Write("Hello World ");
    }
}

class TestChild : BaseClass
{
    public TestChild(int i) : base(i) //send your constuctor to your base class
    { }

    public TestChild()
    { }

    public void Update(int i)
    {
        base.Update(i);
        Console.Write(i.ToString());
    }
}

private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestChild t = new TestChild(); // create instance as your child
    t.Update(100);
}
```

create your object as your child class then call your method and let it call your base class

also if wanna access a or b in base class from your child

```
public int a;
```

`public` it so you can access it from instance you created

`protected` will allow only inside child class to access to it

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void Update(int i)
     {
     a = i;
     TestChild child = new TestChild(); 
     child.Update("Hello World "); 
     }
```

This is where you are assigning value to variable a, and later you instantiated another instance of TestChild class which is different. 
After this instantiation you have to assign the value like

```
    TestChild child = new TestChild();
    child.a = i;
    child.Update("Hello World ");
```

Then you shall get your desired result

Answer (score 0):

This is how to use inheritance:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Dalmata", "Fuffy", 7);
    }
}

class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public string Race { get; set; }

    public Dog(string race, string name, int age) : base(name, age)
    {
        Race = race;
    }
}
```

This way, you will acess Name and Age too, even if they are declared in Animal.